# How can I write a string to a .html file?

Tags: java, output, writer

I am creating a HTML Webpage Generator as part of a college assignment. What I am trying to do is set the header by taking in the users text and saving it to string through the use of a get / set class. However when I try to output the text to file I get an error.

The code I am using to try and output the string is the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        try { 
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\output.html");
            if(!f.exists()) { 
                f.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            fw.write(getHeader());
            fw.close();
        }catch(IOException io) { 
            Logger.getLogger(webPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, io);
        }
    }
```

The error that Eclipse is giving me is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at webPage.main(webPage.java:49)
```

Can anyone help me correct this please?

Comment: `getHeader()` returns null. SO that's the method that you should fix.

Comment: @JBNizet I have a class called Header which should set the header through wp.setHeader( // code here ). Why would it be null when I am sending text through to it to set the string in the get / set class?

Comment: I can't tell anything without seeing the code. Just add `System.out.println(getHeader())` before writing it to your FileWriter, and see by yourself. Or use your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As JB Nizet's comment mentions, `FileWriter.write()` will throw an exception if the argument is `null`.

If you replace your `write` with `fw.write("Hello World")`, you will find no NPE.

So you need to figure out why `getHeader()` is returning `null` and fix that.